# Anidar Childs Routes En Angular

Tags: angular, router, angular-router

Tengo un menú con la siguiente estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cada opción tiene un component propio, es decir:

Menu Principal -> PhMainOutletComponent

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reglas -> ReglasComponent

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando quiero ingresar a cualquier opción de Reglas, no me carga el siguiente componente. Eso me pasa solo cuando anido los Childs Routes.

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core'
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module'
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { PhMainOutletComponent } from '../screens/ph-main-outlet/ph-main-outlet.component'
import { ListasGeneralesComponent } from '../screens/reglas/listas-generales/listas-generales.component'
import { PaisesComponent } from '../screens/reglas/paises/paises.component'
import { TercerosComponent } from '../screens/reglas/terceros/terceros.component'
import { CopropiedadesComponent } from '../screens/reglas/copropiedades/copropiedades.component'
import { RegistroProveedorComponent } from '../screens/administracionproveedores/registro-proveedor/registro-proveedor.component'
import { PersonalProveedorComponent } from '../screens/administracionproveedores/personal-proveedor/personal-proveedor.component'
import { AtencionIncidentesADPComponent } from '../screens/administracionproveedores/atencion-incidentesadp/atencion-incidentesadp.component'
import { ConsulInfoProveedorComponent } from '../screens/administracionproveedores/consul-info-proveedor/consul-info-proveedor.component'
import { ConsulPersoProveedorComponent } from '../screens/administracionproveedores/consul-perso-proveedor/consul-perso-proveedor.component'
import { AsignacionIncidentesComponent } from '../screens/incidentes/asignacion-incidentes/asignacion-incidentes.component'
import { ReporteAtencionIncidentesComponent } from '../screens/incidentes/reporte-atencion-incidentes/reporte-atencion-incidentes.component'
import { ReporteIncidentesComponent } from '../screens/incidentes/reporte-incidentes/reporte-incidentes.component'
import { AtencionIncidentesComponent } from '../screens/incidentes/atencion-incidentes/atencion-incidentes.component'
import { InmueblesComponent } from '../screens/registro/inmuebles/inmuebles.component'
import { PropietarioComponent } from '../screens/registro/propietario/propietario.component'
import { ResidenteComponent } from '../screens/registro/residente/residente.component'
import { VehiculosComponent } from '../screens/registro/vehiculos/vehiculos.component'
import { MascotasComponent } from '../screens/registro/mascotas/mascotas.component'
import { ParqueaderosComponent } from '../screens/registro/parqueaderos/parqueaderos.component'
import { ConsultaCarteraPendienteComponent } from '../screens/pagos/consulta-cartera-pendiente/consulta-cartera-pendiente.component'
import { PazySalvoComponent } from '../screens/pagos/pazy-salvo/pazy-salvo.component'
import { ReciboCajaPagoCuentasComponent } from '../screens/pagos/recibo-caja-pago-cuentas/recibo-caja-pago-cuentas.component'
import { PagoCuentasCobroComponent } from '../screens/pagos/pago-cuentas-cobro/pago-cuentas-cobro.component'
import { ConfiguracionPagoLineaComponent } from '../screens/pagos/configuracion-pago-linea/configuracion-pago-linea.component'
import { HistorialPagosXMesComponent } from '../screens/pagos/historial-pagos-x-mes/historial-pagos-x-mes.component'
import { ReglasComponent } from '../screens/reglas/reglas.component'
import { PagosComponent } from '../screens/pagos/pagos.component'
import { ProveedorComponent } from '../screens/administracionproveedores/proveedor.component'
import { IncidentesMainComponent } from '../screens/incidentes/incidentes-main.component'
import { RegistroComponent } from '../screens/registro/registro.component'
import { ValoresListaComponent } from '../screens/reglas/valores-lista/valores-lista.component';
import { PersonasComponent } from '../screens/reglas/personas/personas.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PhMainOutletComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'PH_REG',
        component: ReglasComponent,
        data: {
          id: 'PH_REG/PH_REG',
          title: 'Reglas'
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'PH_REG_001',
            component: ListasGeneralesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_REG_001',
              title: 'Listas Generales'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_REG_001/PH_REG_001_VAL',
            component: ValoresListaComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_REG_001_VAL',
              title: 'Valores Lista'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_REG_002',
            //redirectTo: '/PH/PH_REG',
            component: PaisesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_REG_002',
              title: 'Paises'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_REG_003',
            redirectTo: '/PH/PH_REG',
            component: TercerosComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_REG_003',
              title: 'Terceros',
              message: 'Terceros en desarrollo'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_REG_004',
            redirectTo: '/PH/PH_REG',
            component: CopropiedadesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_REG_004',
              title: 'Copropiedades'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_REG_005',
            component: PersonasComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_REG_005',
              title: 'Personas'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'PH_PVR',
        component: ProveedorComponent,
        data: {
          id: 'PH_PVR',
          title: 'Administración Proveedores'
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'PH_PVR_001',
            component: RegistroProveedorComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PVR_001',
              title: 'Registro Proveedor'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PVR_002',
            component: PersonalProveedorComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PVR_002',
              title: 'Personal Proveedor'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PVR_003',
            component: AtencionIncidentesADPComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PVR_003',
              title: 'Atención de Incidentes'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PVR_004',
            component: ConsulInfoProveedorComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PVR_004',
              title: 'Consulta Información Proveedor'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PVR_005',
            component: ConsulPersoProveedorComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PVR_005',
              title: 'Consulta Personal Proveedor'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'PH_INC',
        //component: IncidentesMainComponent,
        redirectTo: '/home',
        data: {
          id: 'PH_INC',
          title: 'Incidentes'
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'PH_INC_001',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: ReporteIncidentesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_INC_001',
              title: 'Reporte Incidente'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_INC_002',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: ReporteAtencionIncidentesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_INC_002',
              title: 'Reporte de Atención Incidentes'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_INC_003',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: AsignacionIncidentesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_INC_003',
              title: 'Asignación de Incidentes'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_INC_004',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: AtencionIncidentesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_INC_004',
              title: 'Atención de Incidentes'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'PH_PAG',
        redirectTo: '/home',
        component: PagosComponent,
        data: {
          id: 'PH_PAG',
          title: 'Pagos'
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'PH_PAG_001',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: ConfiguracionPagoLineaComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PAG_001',
              title: 'Configuración Pago en Linea'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PAG_002',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: PagoCuentasCobroComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PAG_002',
              title: 'Pago (Cuentas Cobro)'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PAG_003',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: ReciboCajaPagoCuentasComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PAG_003',
              title: 'Recibo de Caja (Pago Cuentas)'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PAG_004',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: PazySalvoComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PAG_004',
              title: 'Paz y Salvo'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PAG_005',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: ConsultaCarteraPendienteComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PAG_005',
              title: 'Consulta Cartera Pendiente'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_PAG_006',
            redirectTo: '/home',
            component: HistorialPagosXMesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_PAG_006',
              title: 'Historial Pagos Por Mes/Residente'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'PH_RGT',
        component: RegistroComponent,
        data: {
          id: 'PH_RGT',
          title: 'Registro'
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'PH_RGT_001',
            component: PropietarioComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_RGT_001',
              title: 'Propietario'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_RGT_002',
            component: InmueblesComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_RGT_002',
              title: 'Inmuebles'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_RGT_003',
            component: ResidenteComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_RGT_003',
              title: 'Residente'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_RGT_004',
            component: VehiculosComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_RGT_004',
              title: 'Vehículos'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_RGT_005',
            component: ParqueaderosComponent,
            redirectTo: '/PH/PH_RGT',
            data: {
              id: 'PH_RGT_005',
              title: 'Vehiculos'
            }
          },
          {
            path: 'PH_RGT_006',
            component: MascotasComponent,
            data: {
              id: 'PH_RGT_006',
              title: 'Mascotas'
            }
          }
        ]
      }

    ]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PhRoutingModule {

}
```

En la siguiente imagen pueden ver que si ,e está redirigiendo a esa ruta final pero el componente no está siendo cargado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve revisando la documentación de Angular pero no encuentro nada relacionado a lo que quiero hacer, es más, no sé si sea posible hacer esto.

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes hacer con poner rutas hijas? ¿Simplemente quieres que al dar click a un link de tu menú redireccione a ese componente y se renderice una NUEVA PÁGINA? ¿O estás queriendo renderizar componentes dentro de otro componente? Es decir, como si fuese una pequeña página/ventana dentro de otra. Porque podría ser que no necesites hacerlas hijas. Y te podrías evitar de todo esto.

Comment: Realmente lo que quiero es que el router mantenga la jerarquía, por decirlo así. Inicialmente todos eran hijos,
Lo tenía de la forma PH_REG y para los hijos de este, simplmenete le ponía PH_REG/PH_REG_001. Pero me dijeron si era posible que quedara de la forma de Childs Anidados. Y al intentar hacerlo así, pues me ocurre ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas un `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` dentro del HTML de tu ReglasComponent para que todas las rutas hijas de la ruta PH_REG sean renderizadas.

Comment: Gracias, por ahí va la cosa. Me funcionó poniendo esas etiqueta, pero ahora el problema es que si, efectivamente me carga el componente pero el anterior no se elimina.
Es decir, desplaza el menú hacia abajo si pongo el <router-outlet> al inicio del HTML o hacia arriba si lo pongo al final.

Comment: Tienes un problema en el concepto que definiste en tus rutas. Usa solucion facil es todos los hijos del path PH_REG los quites de childrens y los pongas al mismo nivel (hermanos). Y a esas rutas agregales en el path el prefijo PH_REG/. Ya que aunque definiste q son rutas hijas en realidad son rutas hermanas porque quieres que una se oculte cuando las otras se muestren. Si usas rutas hijos el componente del padre que definiste se vera tambien.